# find both min and max quantity and min and max price of that quantity using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have below data and have to find both min and max of price and quantity based on client and prodcode column

[image]

I want output like this

[image]

Comment: Post the code that you have written till now.

Comment: What were your attempts so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `groupby` function in pandas ? that might be useful.

Comment: group by code is giving single values where as I want to display at each row
(later I want to plot it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index('price')
         .groupby(['client', 'Prodcode'])
         .agg(minqnt=('quantity', 'min'),
              priceofmin=('quantity', 'idxmin'),
              maxqnt=('quantity', 'max'),
              priceofmax=('quantity', 'idxmax')))


df = df.join(df1, on=['client', 'Prodcode'])
```

Comment: okay but it is not giving corresponding price values for min and max quantity

Comment: @om9595 - Can you test now?